# SSRS "member not found (exception from HRESULT: 0x80020003 DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND" Visual Studio2019 Community

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, visual-studio-2019, ssrs-tablix

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9QWr.png)Trying to use SSRS in Visual Studio 2019 Community.
I am able to create a new "Report Server Project" Project in VS. However, when I try to "Add New Item" in the Project, I get the Error message:
***Member not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020003 (DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND))***

I did install *Data Server and Processing* when downloading VS and also added the Extensions:

- Microsoft Analysis Services Projects
- Microsoft Reporting Services Projects
- SQL Server Integration Services Projects

Which all seem to be active. I should also note that the "Add New Report" Wizard does work, it's the "Add New Item" that is throwing the error.
Any advice on how to correct?

Thanks to anyone helping!

Comment: Same issue here. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Same problem for me, and I'm using the 'professional' edition of Visual Studio 2019 latest version.  Has a bug report been filed with them for this?

Comment: Still having the issue.. haven’t found a fix yet. Working around it by using the Wizard for now. Seems like it is a bug based on the feedback.

Comment: Same issue here...

Comment: Same issue here

Comment: Same issue here, VS2019 16.8.3

Comment: Same issue for me too. I think is [this](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/shMembersh-shNotsh-shfound/1276989)...

Comment: I'm not getting this issue in version 16.10.3

Answer (score 0):

I got this error and i solved it by adding the references for report viewer libraries in my current project, so basically when you create a new report project those dll are not included by default and visual studio can't find them.. Do a right click on your project and select Manage Nuget packages and install those two packages:

- Corrected.Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms (Current version = 150.1358.0)
- Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Webforms (Current version = 150.1427.0)

Note: i am using Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 but i think the solution will work for 2017 too

Comment: We are talking about SSRS Report Projects. It's not possible to add a reference to any libraries...

Answer (score 0):

So I hit the exact same error and got blocked. After googling for some time, seems MS has accepted that it's a bug, and they have this solution bundled as part of the new Preview ( Visual Studio 2019 version 16.9 Preview 3) and yes this is pretty new, like was release 3 days back when I'm writing this. Once I install and test I'll comment on this thread, but by the release notes (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes-preview#16.9.0.pre.3.0) looks like they've fixed this. I can't wait for the 16.9 to be release (16.9 is still not out), hence installing Preview to continue.

Update: So I installed Udpdate, and then i had to install the reporting service extension again(else it was saying reporting service project to be non-compatible), but post that I'm now able to add a report.

Answer (score 0):

As of 3/8/2021 - I was running Visual Studio Professional 16.8.6 and was experiencing this issue.  I upgraded to 16.9.0 (release data of 3/2/2021).  Unlike `ssethi11`, it did not require the reinstallation of the SSRS extension.

Answer (score 0):

The Official 16.9.1 is released.
Update visual studio and it should work now