The project configuration "NoVariablesDefault|x86" was not found in the project manifest
I am trying to build a legacy xaf 20.2.3 Framework 4.5.2 c# winforms project
When I open the solution I get an error

Current solution contains incorrect configurations mappings.

Opening Configuration Manager shows

In solution explorer I also see a blue icon against the project

and the message "There is no project configuration matching the active solution configuration"  I also see "Pending edit" when I hover over the project in solution explorer.
I am unable to select the Debug, Any CPU configuration that I want.
I found some advice to check the project properties. However when I right click the project in solution explorer and select properties I get an error


An error occurred trying to load the project properties window.  Close
the window and try again. The project configuration
"NoVariablesDefault|x86" was not found in the project manifest.

Update
I have the following in the csProj
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet />
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet />
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'EasyTest|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\EasyTest\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG;EASYTEST</DefineConstants>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet />
  </PropertyGroup>


Checking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52174663/visual-studio-2017-not-treating-csproj-as-a-valid-project-file-after-conversion

Checking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64824124/ssrs-member-not-found-exception-from-hresult-0x80020003-disp-e-membernotfound

For what it is worth I was able to work around the issue by starting a new project and copying files into it from the old project.

Open the.csproj file and make sure that all configurations including NoVariablesDefault|x86 exist correctly. As follows:
<ItemGroup> 
     <ProjectConfiguration Include="NoVariablesDefault|x86"> 
            <Configuration>NoVariablesDefault</Configuration> 
            <Platform>x86</Platform> 
      </ProjectConfiguration> 
 </ItemGroup>


Thank you. I dont actually want such a configuration.
Yet I was unable to work out how to correct it.
I updated my question to show the configurations.
I have solved my problem by starting afresh
